# Complex input validation across two microservices

Tags: architecture, microservices

Let's say that I have two microservices:

- Purchasable Product service - contains thousands of products for sale. It returns the list of products that a particular user can purchase given on the user's region and age.
- Order service - handles the ordering workflow.

When a user places an order, the system has to validate that the products can be bought by the customer. Where do I place that validation?

**Solutions I can think of**

1. Validate in BFF - before placing an order, the BFF will synchronously request Purchasable Product Service to validate that the product is visible to the user. I'm not worried about eventual consistency because the products are always available.

   - Cons: need to ensure that all BFFs and API gateways has this logic.
2. Create a saga - the Order Service send an asynchronous request to Purchasable Product Service to validate the products.

   - Cons: more complex to implementation than option 1.
   - Pros: order service is protected.
3. Have I got my service boundaries/responsibilities wrong?? Should the product filtering be in order service instead? But if I move it to order service, how will the BFF be able to show the list of products? Duplicating the product filtering logic sounds terrible.

Comment: I would argue that in general product service does not sound like a place that should handle logic involving users, membership types etc. But there is not enough information about the system to make a definitive conclusion.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Anyway, regardless of the architecture. How can I validate that the product can be purchased by the user?

Comment: I have renamed Product Service to "Purchasable Product Service". It's job is to run the list of products that a user can purchase. But I'm of course open to another architecture.

Comment: Do you want to perform the validation during the order placement or after the order has been submitted?

Answer (score 1):

BFF is the Backend For FrontEnd.  The point is not to put business logic there, but to assemble various bits so that the frontend does not have to.  If you start assembling the true business bits of your application there, you will end up with a monolith that happens to have microservices wrapping your databases with no logic in them.

I'd say (this is getting closer to opinion) your order service should call the product service.  It has a real-life dependency on it that should be reflected in the application.  Just like in real-life, if you were at a counter trying to buy something, an inventory system (your product service) would be queried to determine what was available for purchase.